# How to mkmapview get location by annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

In my application i have used the `MKmapview` I want to show locations as I drag the pin to pin.

how to get location by pin? I want to show locations as I drag the pin to pin.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
CLLocationDistance distance = 1500;
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, distance, distance);
MKCoordinateRegion adjusterRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];

[self.mapView setRegion:adjusterRegion animated:YES];

self.latitudeValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",userLocation.coordinate.latitude];
self.longtitudeValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",userLocation.coordinate.longitude];


custom *location = [[custom alloc] initWithTitle:@"location" subtitle:@"" location:userLocation.coordinate];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:location];

MKCoordinateRegion regions = {{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
regions.center.latitude = 13.905726;
regions.center.longitude = 100.52142100000003;
regions.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
regions.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

customlocation *locs = [[customlocation alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" subtitle:@"" location:regions.center];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:locs];

}


-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

static NSString *reuseId = @"pin";
MKPinAnnotationView *pa = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
if (pa == nil)
{
    pa = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
    pa.draggable = YES;
    pa.canShowCallout = YES;
}
else
{
    pa.annotation = annotation;
}
    return pa;
}
```

please help me  I want to show location as I drag the pin to pin.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734653/4030948),  This is similar to the answer you looking for except that guy want to get coordinated where user drops the pin.

And here is the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828182/4030948) for the question you asked,